# Snap.svg: How to select all children of outermost SVG element but not from (possibly) nested SVG elements

Tags: css, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to get all (direct) children from the outermost SVG element of the fragment - or in other words: all 2nd-leves elements of the fragment. 
Im using this code: `fragment.selectAll("svg>*")`

This works as long as there is only one SVG element in the given fragment. But if there are nested SVG elements (which is ok according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg ) this returns also elements that are further down in the hierarchical structure - meaning that are 3rd, 4th or of higher levels.

```
<svg id="svg_1" height="380mm" width="490mm" viewBox="0 0 490 380" version="1.0">
    <g id="g_1" transform="translate(57.5,47.5)">
        <svg id="svg_2" version="1.1" height="5" width="5" viewBox="0 0 5 5">
            <path d="m 4.9997035,2.4940359 ... z"/>
        </svg>
    </g>
    <g id="g_2" transform="translate(57.5,97.5)">
        <svg id="svg_3" version="1.1" height="5" width="5" viewBox="0 0 5 5">
            <path d="m 4.9997035,2.4940359 ... z"/>
        </svg>
    </g>
    ...
</svg>
```

I my result, I want only the `g` elements (ids: `g_1` and `g_2`) but I'm getting also the two `path` elements.

It seems promising to replace the line above with this one:
`fragment.select("svg").children()`
However, this one includes a bunch of #text elements which is not included by the original one and I don't know how to remove them from the query result.

Comment: It's just using css selectors, couldn't you use el.selectAll('svg g') or similar ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. But what would be the selector here? The SVG is provided by the user, so I can't assume that it would only contain g's on 2nd level.

Comment: Well I guess you have to decide how you can select the outer SVG element. It may depend if the first element of the fragment is an svg element, or could be something else.